# how to enable/disable NSToolbarItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have a project that needs to disable/enable some `NSToolbarItem`s depends on different options. I checked and found no parameter for this.

Is there a way to enable/disable a given `NSToolbarItem`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implement NSToolbarItemValidation Protocol in your window, view or document controller. The documentation gives the following sample code:

```
-(BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)toolbarItem {

    BOOL enable = NO;
    if ([[toolbarItem itemIdentifier] isEqual:SaveDocToolbarItemIdentifier]) {

        // We will return YES (enable the save item)
        // only when the document is dirty and needs saving
        enable = [self isDocumentEdited];

    } else if ([[toolbarItem itemIdentifier] isEqual:NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier]) {

        // always enable print for this window
        enable = YES;
    }
    return enable;
}
```

You can also use `action` or `tag` to determine what toolbar item is being validated. Items are validated frequently, whenever your app is activated or events are dispatched, so they will always be in a valid state.

Comment: Not so fast. Apple says: "...This message is sent from NSToolbarItem's validate method, however validate will not send this message for items that have custom views." So if you have a button in there, this will not work

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier solution :

```
-(BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)toolbarItem
{

    return [toolbarItem isEnabled] ;
}
```

that way you can use [yourToolBarItem setEnabled:YES/NO] ; in your code.

Comment: clean and nice, have in a fabric class

Answer (score 3):

an easy way to do this in swift, or you could port this to objective c is to just set actions

This Disables the item

```
Mytoolbar.action = nil
```

This reEnables it

```
Mytoolbar.action = "Name of a function"
```

In doing this you would want to replace your IBAction with function so

```
@IBAction func blehbleh(sender: AnyObject){ Stuff }
```

would be changed to

```
func blehbleh(){ Stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

As nsij22 said you need to set action.

In Storyboard just ctrl+drag from toolbar item to your code action.