# How to disable a button of a NSToolbar of macOS X in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar

I would like to enable and disable programmatically a toolbar item (a button) of a NSToolBar in macOS. I tried to create an outlet to ViewController control-dragging but Xcode don't accept the drop. How can I do this?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017822/how-to-enable-disable-nstoolbaritem) about a similar question with Objective-C answers but I'm a beginner and can't understand well how to do this in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the delegate method

```
override func validateToolbarItem(_ item: NSToolbarItem) -> Bool
```

You can distinguish the items for example by the `itemIdentifier` and return `true` to enable and `false` to disable the item

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1524282-validatetoolbaritem) provides an example.