# How to implement validateToolbarItem(_:)?

Tags: swift, cocoa, toolbar

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577092/how-to-disable-a-button-of-a-nstoolbar-of-macos-x-in-swift) and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1524282-validatetoolbaritem) example. I tried to implement a piece of code that enable and disable two buttons (Undo and Redo) in a macOS Toolbar.

```
override func validateToolbarItem(_ toolbarItem: NSToolbarItem) -> Bool {

    var enable = false

    if toolbarItem.itemIdentifier.isEqual("undoButton") {
        enable = (mainTextField.undoManager?.canUndo)!
    }
    else if toolbarItem.itemIdentifier.isEqual("redoButton") {
        enable = (mainTextField.undoManager?.canRedo)!
    }

    return enable
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that the code has not effect. What am I missing?

Comment: `validateToolbarItem` is called on the target of the toolbar item. Is the toolbar item an image toolbar item or a view/control toolbar item? Documentation: [Validating Toolbar Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/ValidatingTBItems.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    enum toolItems:Int {
        case undo = 0
        case redo = 1
    }

    // creating an array at the beginning (AppleDelegate, windowDidLoad, ...) //
    func makeToolbar() {
        toolbarItemState.insert("1", at: toolItems.undo.rawValue) // 0
        toolbarItemState.insert("0", at: toolItems.redo.rawValue) // 1
    }

    override func validateToolbarItem(_ toolbarItem:NSToolbarItem) -> Bool {
        var enable:Bool = false
        if ((toolbarItemState[toolbarItem.tag] as AnyObject).integerValue == 1) {
            enable = true
        }
        return enable
    }

    func editToolItem(index:Int,state:String) -> Void {
        toolbarItemState.replaceObject(at: index, with: state)
    }
```

When the application launches, create an array of toolbarItemState.  If you want to change the state of the undo toolbar item to 'on,' for example,

```
editToolItem(index: toolItems.savePict.undo, state: "1")
```

.  Now, the undo toolbar item is one.  If you set the state to "0," the button will be disabled.