# Disabling Toolbar buttons in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a simple Swift cocoa application. The main window contains:

- a toolbar with some Image Toolbar Items
- a NSViewController (named ViewController)

In ViewController I have implemented:

```
func validateToolbarItem(_ item: NSToolbarItem) -> Bool
```

to enable the buttons as per my requirements.

Unfortunately, the validateToolbarItem is never called.

In an another  Objective-c application I have exactly the same scenario and the function:

```
-(BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)toolbarItem
```

is properly called.

How do I sort this problem out? What do I miss in swift?

Thks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement validateToolbarItem(\_:)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596480/how-to-implement-validatetoolbaritem)

Answer (score 2):

I eventually sorted this out.

The ViewController has to implement NSToolbarItemValidation protocol:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, ..., NSToolbarItemValidation {

    ....

    func validateToolbarItem(_ item: NSToolbarItem) -> Bool {

        return true or false
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I tested this the first time it did't work. I had to restart Xcode to make it working.